# Looking for the best data structure for the job

Tags: c++, qt

I need a data structure to read the following example data:

```
[TAG1]
PROPERTYA=TRUE
PROPERTYB=TRUE
PROPERTYC=TRUE

[TAG2]
PROPERTYA=TRUE
PROPERTYB=FALSE
PROPERTYC=FALSE

etc...
```

Any ideas?

One solution is to have an array of all the properties and another array of the same size with the values. But how would I know which property is under which tag?

Comment: Hint: they are always in the same order.

Comment: What are you doing? Does the name of the property matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a

```
std::map<string, std::map<string, bool> >
```

Construct a new map of string:bool values everytime you hit a [TAG] line, and store all these maps keyed by TAG

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `std::map<string, std::map<string, bool> >` suggested by jrs you may also use some kind of "vector of vectors" structure to store your data which is preferable if performance is a concern.

I will give two examples of scenarious where one of these two will be favoured.

#### When would you prefer a map?

- If you want to look up elements by their tag name or property name you should probably go for a map.

#### When would you prefer a vector?

- If you care for performance of insertion and element access. Inserting elements in a vector will be faster and element access is index-based and therefore constant in time. (No lookup takes place just a single pointer/iterator arithmetic operation.)
- If you'll face (many) iterations over all elements since the contiguous storage will result in a better usage of the cache.

#### How would you store it in a vector?

Each property is a pair of string name boolean.

```
struct props
{
  std::string name;
  bool value;
};
```

Each tag has a name and an arbitrary number of properties in a vector.

```
struct tag
{
  std::string name;
  std::vector<props> properties;
};
```

The data will have an arbitrary number of tags.

```
std::vector<tag> tags;
```

Comment: You first argument for map is wrong. Inserting any item in the map take log(n) (well, in total, log(1) + log(2) + log(3) + ... + log(n) ), which is still approx n*log(n) to insert your n elements. With the vector, adding n element takes O(n) (appending is amortized O(1) ). Conclusion: vector is faster. You would prefer the map only if you want to look up elements by their name.

Comment: +1 with the edit ;-) I would add that you would prefer the vector if you need very fast access to a specific element, since access is O(1) instead of O(log(n)) for the map. So it's more efficient not only because of cache. Bottom line: prefer vector, more efficient in any situation. If you can't because you need access by tag name, use a map.

Comment: Or if you don't care about efficiency. Since maps are probably fast enough in most situation, but more convenient for this usage.

Comment: @Boris You're right since its a balanced tree you'll have a log(n) there. Thanks. The point on access performance is also correct although I suspected it to be obvious (but may be worth adding - i'm going to edit it in).

Comment: To be accurate, I'm right because it is a *search* tree. The fact that it is probably balanced in the Qt implementation doesn't really matter, you still have to place it at the right place in the tree (to be able to retrieve it), which is -at least- log(n), and -worst case- n. Making the tree balanced consists in reorganizing it smartly so that it is also worst case log(n).

Comment: Thank you and appreciate the answer, but performance was not of a concern for my situation although it might be for any readers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Tag class that will have a bool array and string representing the name of the tag. However depending on how you are going to use the information after that and the upper bound of the number of Tags will determine in what data structure you should store the Tag objects. (list, hashtable, array)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Qt, I would in fact elaborate the answer of jrs:

**Default choice:**

```
#include <QMap>
#include <QString>
QMap< QString, QMap<QString, bool> > data;
```

**If performance is critical and you're ok to lose access by name:**

```
#include <QVector>
QVector< QVector<bool> > data;
```